# Do I need primers if ordering from a DNA synthesis provider

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, dna

Do I need to design / synthesize primers for PCR if I am ordering from a DNA synthesis company and they are providing free cloning into my preferred vector backbone? Any good reason to order primers as well?

Comment: It really depend on what you need to do with the plasmid you are ordering. Can you specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you intend to subsequently amplify the DNA you've ordered. I tend to never fully trust anything I don't confirm myself so primers to sequence the insert in the construct they give you might not be a bad idea either.